React native gestures Swipeable with state
I am having issues using the https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/components/swipeable/ component for a simple swiping card app. I suspect it has to do with re-rendering after changing the state, but I don't know how to keep the current card state.
Sometimes it swipes 2 to the right, sometimes not. When the Card component does not go full 100% width, it even renders cards on the side and it looks weird.
I would appreciate any help. Here is the working example (iOS)
https://snack.expo.dev/@tomas.lukac/swipeable-questions
